# Chrome browser doesn't show up when protractor starts testing

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm wondering why my Chrome browser doesn't show when I start testing my angularjs app with protractor. It does execute the test though. I can see the output on my console.

However, if I change the value of browserName to point to firefox and rerun protractor, Firefox will fire up. I'll also see protractor doing its test on the browser.

Comment: Which platform/OS are you on? 1) Are you sure it didn't spawn in the background behind another window? 2) Can you launch chrome programmatically on the cmd line the same way the test spawns it?

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure it didn't get executed. I'm on OSX Mountain Lion. Chrome is version Version 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit). Protractor is version Version 1.3.1

Comment: Did you run webdriver-update or whatever the recommended post-install steps are for OSX?

Comment: No. I'll do some research about that. Thanks.

Comment: Just finished running it and this is what I got - selenium standalone is up to date. chromedriver is up to date. So looks like I have all the latest versions

Comment: Brian, I'm so sorry. You are correct when you first said "spawn in the background". So I closed all my Chrome and restarted protractor. Chrome didn't get activated meaning, it didn't appear as maximized on the screen but was shocked, it was running minimized. When I clicked it, my testing was running on it. Why is it minimized though? Firefox isn't minimized. But I'm glad that there aren't really any issues. My bad.

Comment: Heh, glad it was working all along. ;)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, the chrome browser is running tests in minimized mode where as firefox shows up. any suggestions to eradicate this anomaly??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the impression that my Chrome was not showing up, but I just did not see it as I had too many open Chrome browser windows to even notice the one extra. The real reason I did not see it, was, that I was in full screen mode and the chrome window could not go to the forground as MacOS does not always allow this to happen.

For me I quit my usual Chrome session and then I saw that there was actually a new Chrome session appearing as I started the tests. (I know this is so obvious, but after a long day at work the most obvious things can sometimes lead to be puzzled. So this answer is for the ones who just happened have a bad day ;) )